# Ansible host file refere to first in group

Tags: ansible

Is it possible within an Ansible host file to refer to hosts within a group like my provided sample or is there any other way of doing it directly in the host file? (I would prefer not to change existing playbooks or use limit flags)

```
# Handled by terraform with company policies (can't change this)
[web]
direct-15-67-156-6.bdb.company.com
direct-12-67-116-124.lia.company.com

[lb]
direct-12-68-117-13.osp.company.com

# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
[mywebsite]
web[0]

[gatling]
web[1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do anything like you suggest with a static hosts file, however the static hosts file can be replaced with a script, and then you are free to use whatever logic you wish to build out your groups and hosts. Perhaps you can persuade Terraform to produce the data in a JSON file (or similar) that your inventory script could then consume?

[Docs are here.](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#developing-inventory-scripts)